# Moving all files with the same file name to a folder in C#

Tags: c#, file, directory

I have a folder which contains a bunch of files, for example:

```
example1.mp4
example1-logo.png
example1-footer.png
example2.mp4
example2-logo.png
example2-footer.png
```

The program should create 2 folders with the files inside.

example1 Folder:

```
example1.mp4
example1-logo.png
example1-footer.png
```

example2 Folder:

```
example2.mp4
example2-logo.png
example2-footer.png
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;

CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
dialog.Multiselect = true;
dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
{
    foreach (string folder in dialog.FileNames)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder))
        {
            // Do something with the files
        }
                    
    }
                
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("You must select a folder!", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Not too sure where to go from here, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the files names (without the extensions) by the dash separator to get a string array and group by the first element which is in your example `example1` for the first group, and `example2` for the second one. Then loop the *groups* to create the destination directories, and loop each *group* to copy/move the files.

Here's an example:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

//The caller..
var srcFolder = @"..."; //The source folder.
var desFolder = @"..."; //The destination folder.
var groups = Directory.EnumerateFiles(srcFolder)
    .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
    .GroupBy(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.Name).Split('-').First());

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var groupFolder = Path.Combine(desFolder, group.Key);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(groupFolder);

    foreach (var file in group)
        // Or file.MoveTo(...)
        file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(groupFolder, file.Name), true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
        CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Multiselect = true;
        dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<FileInfo>> fileDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<FileInfo>>();
            foreach (string folder in dialog.FileNames)
            {
                foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles("*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    var existingKey = fileDictionary.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x => file.Name.StartsWith(x));
                    if (existingKey == null)
                    {
                        existingKey = file.Name.Replace(file.Extension,"");
                        fileDictionary[existingKey] = new List<FileInfo>();
                    }

                    fileDictionary[existingKey].Add(file);
                }
            }

            var root = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}root";
            foreach (var dir in fileDictionary.Keys)
            {
                var dirName = $"{root}\\{dir}";
                if (!Directory.Exists(dirName))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
                }
                fileDictionary[dir].ForEach(x => x.CopyTo($"{dirName}\\{x.Name}"));
            }

        }
```

Comment: This almost worked however it has created 6 separate folders instead of 2, image: https://gyazo.com/d16ce83a71b8e177fedc0aab16ea20e8

Comment: If you sort your files by length, it should work. it looks for the all the keys of the dictionary if there exists any key starts with the current file's name.

Answer (score 0):

If they use a known separator character (your example would be a hyphen)  you could have your posted routine read until the character is encountered in the file's name.

Once the hyphen is encountered,  check if a directory exists with the base name. If there's no directory in your working directory, create it.       Afterwards copy the file whose name you are working with to the new one.

I've added code below that assumes the '-' is divider and the files in subfolders.

```
       class Program
    {
        static void CopyToTarget(string Target)
        {

// this local function scans the given file's name and attempts to extract the
// part before the div char. It also trims whitespaces.
            string ExtractName(string Name, char Div)
            {
                StringBuilder BuildName = new StringBuilder();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                {
                    return Name;
                }
                else
                {
                   
                    Name = Name.Trim();

                    if (Name.Contains(Div))
                    {
                        // We walk thru each char and see if it's the Div char
                        for (int step = 0; step < Name.Length; step++)
                        {
                            if (Name[step] == Div)
                                break; 
                            else
                                BuildName.Append(Name[step]);
                        }

 // I found the code does not seem to like spaces so this removes them after getting the part of the file I want.
                        return BuildName.ToString().Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // so we need to figure another way.
                        // this example just returns the original name
                        return Name;
                    }

                }

            }
   
            foreach (var FileEntry in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Target))
            {
                string name = ExtractName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileEntry), '-');
                string DirTarget = Path.Combine(Target, name);

                if (Directory.Exists(DirTarget) == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Made Directory: " + DirTarget);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(DirTarget);

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Directory Already Exists: " + DirTarget);
                }

                DirTarget = Path.Combine(DirTarget, Path.GetFileName(FileEntry));

                Console.Write(string.Format("Copying {0} to {1} ", FileEntry, DirTarget));
                File.Move(FileEntry, DirTarget);


            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
                 CopyToTarget(args[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good tips, can you implement some code?

Comment: The code is a bit on the fragile side I think. There's no exception catching and pretty much assumes every file it looks at will have a divider char.  It should sort the file name given into separate folders like you were looking for as long as there's a unique divider char.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep everything simpler and the most **readable**:

```
        var path = @"X:\Path\To\Target\Folder";
        var folder = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        var files = folder.GetFiles();
        var patterns = new List<Pattern>();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var keyword = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
            foreach (var file2 in files)
            {
                if (file == file2)
                    continue;
                var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file2.Name);
                if (filename.StartsWith(keyword))
                {
                    var pattern = patterns.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Keyword == keyword);
                    if (pattern == null)
                    {
                        patterns.Add(new Pattern
                        {
                            Keyword = keyword,
                            Files = new List<FileInfo>() { file, file2 }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pattern.Files.Add(file2);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var pattern in patterns)
        {
            var folder_to_move =Path.Combine( path ,pattern.Keyword);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder_to_move);
            foreach (var file in pattern.Files)
                file.MoveTo(Path.Combine(folder_to_move, file.Name));
        }
```

This is the Pattern Class:

```
    class Pattern
    {
        public string Keyword { get; set; }
        public List<FileInfo> Files { get; set; }
    }
```

I tested in a real situation and it works like magic:

### Output Example

Folder contents at first:

```
TargetFolder:.
    example1-logo2.txt
    example1-logo3.txt
    example1-movie.txt
    example1.txt
    example2-logo.txt
    example2-video.txt
    example2.txt
```

after running the code:

```
TargetFolder:.
    ├─── example1
    │       example1-logo2.txt
    │       example1-logo3.txt
    │       example1-movie.txt
    │       example1.txt
    │
    └─── example2
            example2-logo.txt
            example2-video.txt
            example2.txt
```